# Change scroll target from div to body

Tags: jquery, scroll, tinyscrollbar

I just want to ask you a question.. do you know how to change the scroll target from div to body when the scroll reaches the top/bottom of this div? i'm using the tinyscrollbar..

thanks!!

Comment: Code you are trying???

Comment: code? its useless to show you the lines because its just a div with a style 'overflow-y: scroll' and then the tinyscrollbar plugin applied to it..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit late ;) Isn't this the standard behaviour? At first the scrollable div scrolls until the bottom is reached, next the windows/body is scrolled until bottom is reached. That's the normal behaviour in IE and Chrome